# How to call WebAPI registered in Azure AD blade(within ADB2C tenant) from a WebApp registered in AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a Azure AD B2C tenant.
Registered a WebApp application in Applications of AD B2C blade.
Registered a WebAPI in Application Registration of Azure Active Directory blade.

I want to give API access to the WebApp to call the above WebAPI.
Is it possible? I don't see an option on the portal to do that. Not sure if its possible via Graph API.

Comment: Are the AAD tenant and B2C tenant a same tenant?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT yes. both are in same tenant. Basically i B2C tenant. Web API application on ADD blade and Web API on B2C blade

Comment: Hi @Raj, I didn't do this things before. However, I don't think it's a good way to do this. B2C tenant is not a common AAD tenant like others, we should use it just for B2C usage.So, I don't recommend you do this . Even you may use this, it may occurs some other issues.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Actual requirement: CompanyA have Web API and Web APP. Web APP is consumer based app. Now CompanyA wants to expose Web API to companyB where they will consume this using client credential flow. If Both WebAPI and WebAPP on B2C blade then client credential flow will not be available right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.

You must register both the web and API apps through the Azure AD B2C blade.

For a .NET sample, see [Call a .NET web API from a .NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet).

Comment: Actual requirement: CompanyA have Web API and Web APP. Web APP is consumer based app. Now CompanyA wants to expose Web API to companyB where they will consume this using client credential flow. If Both WebAPI and WebAPP on B2C blade then client credential flow will not be available right?

Comment: Correct. For the client credentials flow, you must register Company B's web app as a client application and Company A's API app as a resource application through the Azure AD blade, rather than the Azure AD B2C blade. How do users sign in to Company B's web app?

Comment: Basically CompanyB's Web API or backend services will only consumes CompanyA's web API. So CompanyB Web API and CompanyA's Web API both should be registered under Azure AD blade right

Comment: Basically CompanyB's Web API or backend services will only consumes CompanyA's web API. So CompanyB Web API and CompanyA's Web API both should be registered under Azure AD blade right. My doubt here is CompanyA Web API is consumed by CompanyA's Web APP registered under B2C blade (since it is consumer based app where users login via google, ..) and CompanyB's Web API both. So here what is the solution ?. Do i need to register CompanyA's Web API on Both Azure AD blade and Azure AD B2C blade ?